# How to make a pop-up alert when user did not enter email

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I need jquery script, to show pop up, when user did not enter email to the field after being at site 1 min. And redirect to another page if he enter his email. I have the pop up itself. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you try to setTimeout ?

Comment: yes, I can set Timeout, but I can't do other things.

Comment: Please check, I have given sample.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go, change the time to how many seconds you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 var i=0;
    counterControl = setInterval(function()
    { 
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML=i++; 
    if(i==10 && $("#emailInput").val()=="") {
      clearInterval(counterControl);
            document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML="Time over"; 
            alert("You have missed the timeslot for entering email-id");
            }
     else if(i>10 && !$("#emailInput").val()==""){window.location = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions";}
            
    }, 1000);

    
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="clock">Time given: 10 seconds </div> </br>

Enter E-mail id: <input type="text" id="emailInput"/>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it , starts at one minute in the future and decrease seconds (1000 in millis) .

Here there is a link where you can find explanation about the function [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
var timetowait = (new Date().getTime()+1*60000);
setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var oneminute = timetowait - now;
    var seconds = Math.floor((oneminute%(1000*60))/1000);    
    if (seconds < 0) {
       //dosomething       
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a timeout on page load and, after the timeout is triggered, check if the email filed is empty.

```
window.onLoad=function(){
    setTimeout(checkEmail,1000*60);
};
function checkEmail(){
    if(jQuery("#idInput").val()==""){
        alert("pop-up");
        //pop-up will be show
    }
    else{
        window.location="http://www.newUrl.com";
        //browser will be redirect
    }
}
```

i don't know what you mean by pop-up

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it.